# Puppet - Any way to copy predefined custom configuration files for software on clients from the puppet master (host)?

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

I have been having a lot of fun coding with what puppet I have had experience with so far, and so far it looks like it can do most of what I need it to do.

One thing I am not finding in the documentation (with some searching) is how to (if it is possible) have pre-built configuration files to use on the servers. For example:

I use puppet to install httpd. Now we have apache on the client. Well now the httpd.conf needs some customization and specific settings. I have the httpd.conf I need to use on the puppet master. How do I get it from the puppet master to the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went on the IRC channel for puppet, and found out this can be done with the source attribute.

```
file { "/etc/firewall.sh":
    owner => root,
    group => root,
    mode => 550,
    source => "puppet:///files/iptables.sh"
}
```

the location of files is set in /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf - the configuration there is straightforward.

The content tag instead of source can be used to put a literal string into the file.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I'd use the `puppet:///modules/<module name>/iptables.sh` format.  That way everything is confined to module and and you don't need a fileserver.conf.  The `puppet:///modules/*` is free.

Answer (score 0):

Using static files is a good start. Using templates is even better, and more flexible in the long run.

You can read the [Puppet Template Documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_template.html)

Example:

```
$hostname = 'your.host.com'
$portnum  = 8080

file { '/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf':
   ensure => present,
  content => template('lighttpd/lighttpd.conf.erb'),
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
     mode => 0644,
}
```

This combined with a .erb template creates the desired config file using the variables $hostname and $portnum.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^<%= hostname %>" {
    proxy.server = (
        "" => (
            (
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => <%= portnum %>
            )
    ...
```