# Puppet - how can I copy a file to several user folders?

Tags: user-management, puppet, deployment

Well I was using the info on this:

[Puppet - Any way to copy predefined custom configuration files for software on clients from the puppet master (host)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/155144/puppet-any-way-to-copy-predefined-custom-configuration-files-for-software-on-c)

But I need some more elaborated, because I have several Desktops and are in use by 2 or 3 users each one, so I want to make a class for copy a shortcut in his desktops.

The computers are joined to a domain, so any user can log in any desktop, and his profile is created in every desktop.

I've tryed with this:

```
class applink {

  file { "/home/installer/Escritorio/Workdesktop.desktop":
       owner => installer,
       group => root,
       mode => 770,
       source => "puppet://$server/files/Workdesktop.desktop"            
 }
```

This is only for one user called "installer", how can do this for several users?

Can I use `$USER` for do this? Any Thoughts?

Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

There are really two ways to do this: a definition or a virtual resource. I know more about definitions so that's the approach I'll describe. [Read about virtual resources here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/virtual_resources.html), but be ready to get confused before you gain understanding.

To do this in a definition, create a manifest in your [module structure](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/modules.html) to contain it; in your example it'd be in `_modulepath_/applink/manifests/desktoplinks.pp`

```
define applink::desktoplinks {
  file { "/home/$title/Escritorio/Workdesktop.desktop":
    owner => $title,
    group => root,
    source => "puppet://$server/files/Workdesktop.desktop",
  }
  # you could have others here if you wanted
}
```

Then to use it, you would call it with each user's name, perhaps all at once in an array:

```
applink::desktoplinks { [ "user1", "user2", "user3" ]: }
```

The trick is that the username is the "title" of the defined resource, so it is available inside the definition as `$title`.  Read more about [defined types here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_tutorial.html#resource-collections).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I just learned another way to do this. It's more of a syntax quirk than anything, but here you go:

```
file { ["/home/installer/Escritorio/Workdesktop.desktop",
        "/home/user/Escritorio/Workdesktop.desktop"]:
  owner => installer,
  group => root,
  mode => 770,
  source => "puppet://$server/files/Workdesktop.desktop"            
}
```

The key is specifying the `title` as an array instead of a string; Puppet will parse this as though you'd written the following:

```
file { "/home/installer/Escritorio/Workdesktop.desktop":
  owner => installer,
  group => root,
  mode => 770,
  source => "puppet://$server/files/Workdesktop.desktop"            
}
file { "/home/user/Escritorio/Workdesktop.desktop":
  owner => installer,
  group => root,
  mode => 770,
  source => "puppet://$server/files/Workdesktop.desktop"            
}
```

i.e., you get both `File["/home/installer/Escritorio/Workdesktop.desktop"]` and `File["/home/user/Escritorio/Workdesktop.desktop"]` bound in your configuration.

I suspect that this would work for many types of resources, but I haven't tested any other than `file`.